# How to containerize, using Docker, a pipeline that already runs on a conda environment and has a combination of Python and R scripts?

Tags: python, r, bash, docker

I'm new to docker and still getting familiar with the logic of containerization.

I need to containerize a legacy pipeline that runs all its steps, including activating its conda environment, from a single bash scripts called `main.sh`. `main.sh` calls a combination of Python and R scripts and it'd normally be invoked from the command line with a simple `./main.sh`. The pipeline and its conda environment have already been tested; thus, I'd like to containerize it with the least amount of changes.

A reduced version of main.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate my_env

python python_script.py
Rscript r_script.py
```

my_env already contains all the python modules and R libraries necessary for the scripts to operate.

I tried creating a WDL file an running it with cromwell:
`mywf.wdl`

```
version 1.0
workflow mywf {
    call mywf
}

task mywf {
        command <<<
                ./main.sh
        >>>
        output {
                String out = read_string(stdout())
        }
}
```

Which I then run as:

```
java -jar cromwell-85.jar run mywf.wdl
```

But running this piece of code produces the following error:

```
./main.sh: No such file or directory
```

which indicates the wdl isn't evening detecting the main script. What is this error and how can I solve it? Is there a way to automatize the generation of the mywf.wdl so it containerizes the pipeline **with** the environment.

Comment: Do you have a Dockerfile defining the container? Did you copy the main.sh script into the container? Or what's it's path inside the container?

Comment: There is no Dockerfile yet. I'm starting the container from scratch.

Comment: usually you want to `COPY ./main.sh main.sh` in the dockerfile to copy the main shell script into the container before you run it

Comment: Also i can tell you that `source ./conda.sh` from main.sh will not work as you expect it to. You will want to `RUN conda init bash && . ~/.bashrc ` in the dockerfile before `conda create` etc also form the dockerfile.